# How to .off() an .on() action with different selectors

Tags: jquery

Code link here - http://jsfiddle.net/V5g2m/

```
var $template = $('div.main');

$template.off('change.filterIt', 'select.filter')
    .on('change.filterIt', 'select.filter', function(){
    alert(1);
});

$template.off('change', 'select.filter[name="source"]')
    .on('change.getNewSource', 'select.filter[name="source"]', function(){
    alert(2);
});
```

Can anyone help me with my question - how to unbind event **change.filterIt** from only this selector **select.filter[name="source"]**. It should stay to others **select.filter** elements, but not trigger on current.

Comment: *"...but not trigger on current."* What do you mean by "current"?

Comment: select.filter[name="source"]

Answer (score 0):

Filter it out with `:not()` before you add the event

```
var $template = $('div.main');

$template.off('change.filterIt', 'select.filter')
.on('change.filterIt', 'select.filter:not([name="source"])', function(){
    alert(1);
});

$template.off('change', 'select.filter[name="source"]')
    .on('change.getNewSource', 'select.filter[name="source"]', function(){
    alert(2);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/V5g2m/2/)

Comment: It's correct, thank you, but I want to know "how to unbind", not "how to not bind".